# Accessing list elements in a list of lists in prolog to operate on

Tags: list, prolog

I've been trying to work this out for a good hour now, and am not having any luck.

If I have a list of lists like so

```
[[tom, dick, harry], [janice, jane, jess]]
```

And they have the relations

```
happy(tom).
happy(dick).
happy(harry).
happy(janice).
unhappy(jane).
unhappy(jess).
```

I want to query each list individually and find out if they are unhappy or happy. Currently I have written two functions to handle this, they are

```
%% Female happiness checker
hcf([]).
hcf([H|T]) :-
   happy(H),
   hcf(T).

%% Male happiness checker
hcm([]).
hcm([H|T]) :-
   happy(H),
   hcM(T).
```

So currently individually these do work. If I put in

```
hcm([Janice, jess, jane]).
false
```

It returns false, as two people are unhappy.

What I am having trouble with is writing a function which allows me to pass each list from the list of lists into respective functions for each male and female happiness.

So Far I have tried something along the lines of

```
%% I  was trying to get a HEAD list and a TAIL list to pass them through but didn't have much luck
happnieschecker([[]])
happnieschecker([[H|T]]) :-
some code here
```

EDIT : I want the program to run like so

```
happinesschecker([tom, dick, harry], [janice, jane, jess]).
false - since jane and jess are unhappy
happinesschecker([tom, dick, harry], [janice]).
true - since everyone is happy
```

So my question is, how can I pass every second list into HCF for females and every other list into HCM for males?

Comment: Given an example how your relation should be used! Pretend it is already written.

Comment: @false my apologies, totally overlooked that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prolog list (`[a,b,c]`) is *syntactic sugar* for the data structure `./2`, with the empty list denoted by the *atom* `[]`.

- the list `[a]` is exactly identical to `.(a,[])`
- the list `[a,b]` is exactly identical to `.(a,.(b,[]))`
- the list `[a,b,c]` is exactly identical to `.(a,.(b,.(c,[])))`

Myself, I'd rather use the square bracket notation. You?

Prolog's list notation offers more syntactic sugar, using the `|` operator to partition the list into a *head* and a *tail*.

- The notation `[a|X]` is exactly identical to `.(a,X)
- the notation `[a,b|X]` is exactly identical to `.(a,.(b,X))`
- the notation `[a,b,c|X]` is exactly identical to `.(a,.(b,.(c,X)))`

Given that, and assuming your list-of-lists contains alternating sublists of males and females:

```
[ [bob,ted] , [carol,alice] , [tom,dick,harry] , [jane,sally,simone] ]
```

something like this should work for you

```
everybody_happy( []         ) .                 % the empty list is all happy
everybody_happy( [Ms]       ) :-                % a list of length 1 contains a male sublist
  findall( M , (member(M,Ms),happy(M)) , Ms )   % is everybody happy?
  .                                             %
everybody_happy( [Ms,Fs|Ps] ) :-                % a list of length 2+ starts with a male and female sublist
  findall( M , (member(M,Ms),happy(M)) , Ms ) , % are all the boys happy?
  findall( F , (member(F,Fs),happy(F)) , Fs ) , % are all the girls happy?
  everybody_happy(Ps)                           % is the remainder of the list happy?
  .                                             % easy!
```

I'm using `findall/3` here. If you want to roll your own happiness checker, just replace `findall/3` with your implementation:

```
everybody_happy( []         ) .  % the empty list is all happy
everybody_happy( [Ms]       ) :- % a list of length 1 contains a male sublist
  is_happy(Ms)                   % is everybody happy?
  .                              %
everybody_happy( [Ms,Fs|Ps] ) :- % a list of length 2+ starts with a male and female sublist
  is_happy( Ms ) ,               % are all the boys happy?
  is_happy( Fs ) ,               % are all the girls happy?
  everybody_happy(Ps)            % is the remainder of the list happy?
  .                              % easy!

is_happy([]).        % the empty list is happy
is_happy([P|Ps] ) :- % a non-empty list is happy IF... 
  happy(P) ,         % - its head is happy, and
  is_happy(Ps)       % - its tail is happy
  .                  % easy!
```

Edited to note: if you want to discard the first item, try something like

```
everybody_happy( [_|Xs] ) :-
  every_body_happy_1( Xs )
  .
```

where `everybody_happy_1/1` is the actual predicate.

Comment: Thank you for a very complete answer and explanation!

Comment: Nicholas Carey, is there a particular way I can disregard the first element of a list when using this? i.e. always start the recursion from i guess index 1 rather than index 0?

Comment: The variable `_` is the *anonymous variable*. Every instance of it, even within the same predicate is unique, so something like `1 ?- _=3,_=4.` evaluates to `true`. You might want to get Sterling & Shapiro's [*The Art of Prolog*](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/art-prolog). It will help you grok Prolog.

Comment: I ended up just splitting the H and T and calling the function above like split([H|T]) :- everbody_happy(T). :)

Comment: @Jim: Note that the first version of `everybody_happy([[X]]).` incorrectly fails should there be more than one happy person.

Comment: @false the one with 3x findall?

Comment: @false invalid in terms what however like a real world application of this?

Comment: @Jim: Take `everybody_happy([[X]]).` It means: Is there an `X` such that `X` is happy? O.t.o.h: `everbody_happy([[tom]]).` succeeds. So there is `X = tom` which should be an answer. And more than that...

Answer (score 2):

```
happynesschecker(Ms, Fs) :-
   allhappy(Ms), % more compactly:  maplist(happy,Ms).
   allhappy(Fs). 

allhappy([]).
allhappy([P|Ps]) :-
   happy(P),
   allhappy(Ps).
```

Note that the very same predicate can be used for both the males and females list.

And for a list of list of persons:

```
extrahappy(Mss) :-
   maplist(maplist(happy), Mss).
```

or more verbosely:

```
extrahappy([]).
extrahappy([Ps|Pss]) :-
   allhappy(Ps),
   extrahappy(Pss).
```

Comment: What if i had like 3 lists inside the list of lists? Males, females, Males