# Prolog: Find positve numbers in a given list

Tags: prolog

I would like to know how to find a sublist of positive numbers in a given list `L`, example:

L = [-1, 5, 3, -7, 10]

Sublist = [5, 3, 10]

I tried:

```
pos_sublist([], []).
pos_sublist(H|L, LO) :- H>=0, pos_sublist(L, H|LO).
```

How could I implement the recursion part?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68459530/17628336

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on list notation (for which, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24044032/467473) to the question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043039/accessing-list-elements-in-a-list-of-lists-in-prolog-to-operate-on".

Since you are omitting the `[...]` square brackets, you no longer have lists: you just have the [nested] data structure `'|'/2`.

The easiest way to select non-negative (*positive* meaning 'greater than zero', as zero does not have a sign) values from a list is a combination of  `member/2` and `findall/3`:

```
positive_nums(Xs,Ps) :- findall(P, (member(P,Xs), P >= 0), Ps ) .
```

Rolling your own, though, isn't much more complex:

```
positive_nums( []     , []     ) .
positive_nums( [X|Xs] , [X|Ys] ) :- X >= 0, !, positive_nums(Xs,Ys) .
positive_nums( [_|Xs] ,    Ys  ) :-            positive_nums(Xs,Ys) .
```

Comment: Can you comment on whether it is better to use a cut `!` or to put in the `X < 0` condition in the third predicate?

Comment: Also, strictly speaking, zero is neither positive or negative. It possibly should be `X > 0` only.

Comment: Guarding the 3rd clause with `X < 0` works, too.. I like using the cut, because that eliminates the additional choice points. WIth the cut, the predicate simply succeeds with no alternatives; without the cut and with the additional test, the predicate succeeds  with an alternative available (which fails). Depending on your application, not pruning the search tree like that can have performance implications.